# `ctx.prisma.status is not a function` error, even though it's defined

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, prisma, express-graphql

I am using the setup in "build an app" of the getting started guide, albeit slightly modified in terms of directory structure.

I am receiving the following error when trying to run a basic query against the graphql-yoga playground at localhost:4444.

You can see that `status` is defined on the schema, so why isn't this working?

I'm even having a tough time inserting data on localhost:4466/_admin, and straight up cannot insert data unless it's done through the example script autogenerated mutation `const testing = await prisma.createcnStatus({ ticker: 'XXX' })` which works fine.

***Query***

```
query {
  status {
    ticker
  }
}
```

***Error***

```
  "data": {
    "status": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "ctx.prisma.status is not a function",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "status"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`app.js`

```
require('./lib/main')
```

`/lib/main.js`

```
const { prisma } = require('./generated/prisma-client')
const { GraphQLServer, PubSub } = require('graphql-yoga')
const resolvers = require('./resolver')
const fs = require('fs')

const pubsub = new PubSub()
const server = new GraphQLServer({
  typeDefs: './lib/schema.graphql',
  resolvers,
  context: {
    prisma,
    pubsub
  }
})

let port = 4444
server.start({
    port: port,
  },
  () => console.log('Server is running on http://localhost:' + port)
)
```

`/lib/resolver.js`

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    status(parent, args, ctx, info) {
      return ctx.prisma.status()
    }
  }
}

module.exports = resolvers
```

`/lib/schema.graphql`

```
type Query {
  status: [cnStatus]
}

type cnStatus {
  ticker: String
}
```

`datamodel.prisma`

```
type cnStatus {
  id: ID! @id
  ticker: String
}
```

Comment: please share this file ./generated/prisma-client.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the datamodel you gave, Prisma will generate the client for CRUD operations.

Since its generated based on the name of the types, it should be something along the line of:

```js
ctx.prisma.cnStatus()
```

Answer (score 0):

shoule be ctx.prisma.cnStatus() here

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    status(parent, args, ctx, info) {
      return ctx.prisma.status()
    }
  }
}
```

and you require array in schema, but return instance in query resolver

```
type Query {
  status: [cnStatus]
}
```